# Quickly clean the apartment before someone comes over

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I'm trying to remember a single word that means 'to quickly clean your apartment or house right before someone comes over'.

If I can recall correctly, it starts with an 'S'. I also thought it was along the lines of 'Scuttlebang' or 'Scuttlefunge', but neither come back with anything. Thanks!

Comment: *Cat lick* the apartment.

Comment: I've heard of _give it a cat lick_, suggesting something that adjusts the top coat or surface appearance, but I'd most assuredly forgotten it until you reminded me. Something mothers say as they wipe smuts from the faces of their children with a wet tissue.  +1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

***'Scurrifunge'*** or ***'Scurryfunge'***

From the Oxford English Dictionary:

> scurrifunge ˈscurrifunge, v.dial.
>   Also scurry-.
>   [A word of jocular formation, used in various senses with little or no discoverable connexion.]
>   a. ? trans. To scrub, scour. b. intr. (See quot. 1777.) c. ? To wriggle about.
>   *1777 Horæ Subsecivæ (MS.) in Eng. Dial. Dict., s.v. Scurrifunge, to lash tightly; coïre. 1789 Cowper Let. to Lady Hesketh 6 June, Half a dozen tooth brushes... Two of the brushes abovesaid must be for inside scurryfunging, viz. they must be hooked. 1894 Punch 1 Sept. 102/1 So he scurryfunged around with his stomach on the ground,..And he spied ‘a stag of ten’.*

The word has had a bit of a revival lately in the sense that the OP suggested:

> Scurryfunge (verb)
>   sku-ree-fun-j
>   Old English; to rush around cleaning when company is on their way over. 
>   Not in use much nowadays but it really should be, I scurryfunge.
>
> Example sentences
>   *“Putting the phone down to my neighbour, I had a quick scurryfunge before she rang the doorbell”*
>
> *“Whenever my mother-in-law was due for a visit, I’d have to have a scurryfunge no matter how tidy my house was.”*

From 'Word of the Day – Scurryfunge' By Shan Williams July 29, 2015.  (http://forreadingaddicts.co.uk/word-of-the-day/word-of-the-day-scurryfunge/3166)

The very interesting origins of the word (in Old English and Old Norse) are discussed by EL&U members at length in this post: [Is "scurryfunge" a new word?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/266999/is-scurryfunge-a-new-word)

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much! I thought I was going to go crazy trying to figure it out!!

Comment: A completely new word for me!   What my mother would have said (northeastern US):  "I'll just give it a lick and a promise."

Comment: @ab2- Yep, I've never heard that either.  I would have said, ***straighten up***.

Comment: i've never heard of this one ... but i like it! might try to start using it.

Answer (score 3):

Consider,

> ***square away***
>
> Put in order; also, get ready for. For example, Once *we've got the
> files squared away, we can decide on next year's repertory*, or *She had
> to square away the house before leaving town*. This expression uses
> square in the sense of "arrange in accordance with some principle,"
> indirectly alluding to the geometric square. [Early 1800s] [The American Heritage® Dictionary of Idioms](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/square+away)
>
> *“He's not wakin' up, Sergeant,” reported Dayton. “Should we call
> sickbay?” “Why bother? He's just another drunk marine,” retorted the
> sergeant. “I'll deal with him. Meanwhile, square away this shit,
> square away your room, then come down to  the guard shack for a little
> chat* [The Marine of 8th and I](https://books.google.fr/books?id=kVzBFqvjK6EC&pg=PA12&dq=%22square+away+your+room%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAGoVChMIo92G-Ib6yAIVilYaCh10nwuH#v=onepage&q=%22square%20away%20your%20room%22&f=false)
>
> ***square up***
>
> *Scot* to tidy up [Cambridge English Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/square+up)